# why my url shows all index actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

in my asp.net mvc project all links shows index action
for example :

> localhost:1559/Home/Index 
>   localhost:1559/about-us/Index 
>   localhost:1559/contact-us/Index 
>   localhost:1559/portfolio/Index

why it does not hide the index action ?

I want to show like this :

> localhost:1559/Home 
>   localhost:1559/about-us 
>   localhost:1559/contact-us 
>   localhost:1559/portfolio

this is my global file codes :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.Add(
            new Route("{controller}/{action}/{Q1}/{Q2}",
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", Q1 = UrlParameter.Optional, Q2 = UrlParameter.Optional }),
                    new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
            );
            routes.Add(
            new Route("{controller}/{action}/{Q1}",
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", Q1 = UrlParameter.Optional }),
                    new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
            );
            routes.Add(
            new Route("{controller}/{action}",
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}),
                    new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
            );
        }
```

who can help me ?

Comment: what happened when you tried to navigate to : `localhost:1559/Home` ?
if it's working fine then you will simply need to remove the "/index" part from your links, and everything should be working fine.

Comment: it goes to localhost:1559/Home/Index

Comment: Hi Persian, did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
new Route("{controller}/{action}/{Q1}",
```

use

```
new Route("{controller}/{Q1}",
```

for each one (you'll have to adjust to accommodate the parameters).

The reason this is happening is because your action is called "index". Therefore your route is filling in the placeholder {action} with the name of the action which is "index".